# JasperReports mysterious reapting values

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have an extraordinarily annoying error with JasperReports/iReport. I have recently gone from version 3.6.1 to 4.5.1 and it is still present.

I have a report that pulls out some information from a MS SQL server database, via a jdbc `DataSource` that executes a stored procedure. The problem is I am getting random lines of data with only a single value on them like so:

```
ID    Name        Marketing_Preferences
1     John        Y
2     James       N
3     Daniel      Y
                  Y
4     Tim         N
```

I have looked at the original data over and over and over, and there is nothing different or special about the lines that do this.

The related iReport xml definitions are:

```
<field name="Marketing_Preferences" class="java.lang.String"/>

<staticText>
    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="504" y="41" width="101" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean( $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() == 1 )]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement>
        <font size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[Marketing_Preferences]]></text>
</staticText>

<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="504" y="3" width="101" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
    <textElement>
        <font size="8"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Marketing_Preferences}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Through trial and error and using the condition print expressions I have found that the double ups are tied to one output row, so if I tell `Marketing_Preferences` to not print when `ID = 3` then neither of the values will print.

Firstly, does anyone know how or why this could occur? As I said I have checked the original data many times, and cannot find any reason for it to occur, running the stored procedure does not produce the above at all.

Secondly, does anyone know a way I can work around it? Some way to tell iReport not to print the next value if it think's it's a list, or limit to only one line per result. I cannot use the 'Print repeated values' as this then doesn't print repeating values that are valid.

Any help is appreciated !!!

Comment: Can we see the value part of the `Marketing_Preferences` in JRXML ?

Comment: Whoops, @RangiLin have included it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you have your `Marketing_Preferences` text field `isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"`

here is the javadoc from `JRElement`

> isPrintWhenDetailOverflows() 
>             If this is set to true, the element will be reprinted on the next page if the band does not fit in the current page.

Comment: Despite the fact that I am 99% sure I have tried changing that before with no effect... it does seem to have worked! I just want to do some more testing before I accept your answer to be sure but seems like you may have solved it!

Comment: @dann.dev You can check whether those repeated values are always come from the row that across two page.